# Upload file/image into server using Coroutine + Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I am new coroutines I try to upload file into server (using Retrofit 2.9.0) but I didn't get the response. Below is my code:

```
private suspend fun uploadFile(inputFiles: List<String>,channel:Channel<Any>): List<FileResponse>? {
        val partList = buildFilePart(inputFiles)
        QLog.d(TAG,"uploadFile going 1")
        val response = RequestHelper.getUpLoadFilesKotlinRequest().uploadFiles(partList)
        QLog.d(TAG,"uploadFile going 2")
        return response.body()
}
interface UploadFileApiKotlin {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/uploadFile")
    suspend fun uploadFiles(
        @Part listUri: List<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Response<List<FileResponse>?>
}
```

After checking logcat, I saw only one line of code:

> uploadFile going 1

There is no log line: *uploadFile going 2*

It seems that coroutine is suspended at line : `val response = RequestHelper.getUpLoadFilesKotlinRequest().uploadFiles(partList)`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Coroutine can't be suspended at that point, bcz `uploadFiles()` is not marked with `suspend` keyword. Try to mark it with `suspend` keyword and return `List<FileResponse>?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70433436/5856328) and finally I got the answer for myself

```
suspend fun uploadFile() = suspendCoroutine<Response<List<FileResponse>?>> { continuation ->
    val call = RequestHelper.getUpLoadFilesKotlinRequest().uploadFiles(partList)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Response<List<FileResponse>?>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
            response: Response<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>
        ) {
            // Resume coroutine with a value provided by the callback
            continuation.resumeWith(response.data)
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(t)
        }
    })
}
```