# Suspend Coroutines's execution to wait for callback

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Recently, I applied Coroutines into my project everything seems to be fine but today I meet a problem [Upload file/image into server using Coroutine + Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70360995/5856328).

It seems that there is no solution for upload file using coroutine + Retrofit, so we must use callback for retrofit.

```
//Api interface
interface UploadFileApiKotlin {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/uploadFileApi")
    fun uploadFiles(
        @Part listUri: List<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>
}
//ViewModel class
serviceScope.launch {
                //Insert into db
                repository.insertNewExtAct()
                //Send data into server.
                val call = RequestHelper.getUpLoadFilesKotlinRequest().uploadFiles(partList)
                call.enqueue(object : Callback<Response<List<FileResponse>?>> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
                        response: Response<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>
                    ) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(
                        call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
                        t: Throwable
                    ) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })
                //Wait for response from server and do logic
            }
```

My question is: How can I suspend coroutines's execution to wait for retrofit's callback ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to work with callbacks (to convert a callback to a `suspend` function):

```
serviceScope.launch {
    //Insert into db
    repository.insertNewExtAct()
    //Send data into server.
    uploadFile()
    //Wait for response from server and do logic
}

suspend fun uploadFile() = suspendCoroutine<Response<List<FileResponse>?>> { continuation ->
    val call = RequestHelper.getUpLoadFilesKotlinRequest().uploadFiles(partList)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Response<List<FileResponse>?>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
            response: Response<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>
        ) {
            // Resume coroutine with a value provided by the callback
            continuation.resumeWith(response.data)
        }

        override fun onFailure(
            call: Call<Response<List<FileResponse>?>>,
            t: Throwable
        ) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(t)
        }
    })
}
```

[`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) suspends coroutine in which it executed until we decide to continue by calling appropriate methods - `Continuation.resume...`. `suspendCoroutine` mainly used when we have some legacy code with callbacks.

There is also [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) builder function, it behaves similar to `suspendCoroutine` with additional feature - provides an implementation of `CancellableContinuation` to the block.

Comment: This solution is work. Thank you bro.